# Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 with samba, and Windows network siblings. How to share printer drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, samba, hp

(guys!)

Ladies and Gentlemen!

Recently I've installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS with Samba, CUPS and HPLIP drivers (the printer I'm using is a Hewlett-Packard m1120 MFP connected to the server with USB).

The printer is shared in CUPS and is seen and works from other Linux workstations. On a Windows machine, it is also seen in the network as "server's HP-LaserJet... printer" when I click "Add a new Network or Bluetooth printer". However, when I click the "Add" button in Windows it displays the dialog, that informs the user, there is no driver for that printer, and asks the user to select a manufacturer and a model form a list:

[image: 1]

I have downloaded the Windows drivers from HP's website, but don't know how to grant them to the Windows PC's, trying to install and use the printer, so it would be immediately recognized and installed. How my `[print$]` share in `smb.conf` should look, where should I put the drivers (I will use only 64-bit Windows installations) and what kind of files should I put in these directories (`.inf`, `.cab`, `.dll`, etc.)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as your first sentence goes "guys!" I just want to point out  there are some ladies here too and at least one of them (Zanna) is a lot more knowledgeable than me when it comes to Ubuntu and sweet potato chips.

Comment: "guys" is used in the meaning of "people" here, just a little more casual :) Sorry for the confusion, just English is not my native language and sometimes, I experience situations like this one. Check the update :)